# Mac QGIS 3.0, env: python3: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, macos, installation, qgis

I'm getting started with QGIS 3.0 on Mac. I installed python 3.6 with the python.org installer as directed by kyngchaos.com/software/qgis.

The python console in qgis works fine. Though running geoprocessing tasks, such as reclass, results in an error - env: python3: No such file or directory

How can I point QGIS to my python 3.6 directory? Anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: I'm having trouble, too; happens when I try to create virtual rasters. Additionally, I seem to have problems with basic functions. I can't clip, getting responses like "no such file or directory" if I remember correctly from the top of my head. Came here to find people with similar problems. (I'm new to Mac OS & all Apple products, uses 2.18 on a Windows PC before.)

Comment: I resolved it by adding the path to python to the runtime configuration of QGIS using the instructions found at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107204/system-variable-path-overwritten-in-qgis for extending system variables. In this case the PATH variable

Answer (score 0):

There are some known issues with QGIS installs on Mac.  The security settings prevent complete installs of the python and gdal packages associated with QGIS. These must be installed separately from QGIS, then the PATH variable in GIS settings must be pointed at these dependencies.
See this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366848/scp-plugin-for-qgis-3-10-on-mac?fbclid=IwAR2bBRC5V-6JSKZax9jOuhFMcwGhPhfbYEoHgHK8VF6vrVDhePSaPvjHghk) for a fix.